# How to retrieve request method within body of the endpoint's function?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Say I have a controller and this is my endpoint. How would I do something similar to what I have in the body?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/path/**", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> getResponse(@PathVariable UUID varId) {
   HttpMethod httpMethod = foo();
   if (httpMethod == httpMethod.GET) {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject an instance of `HttpServletRequest` to your method.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/path/**", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> getResponse(@PathVariable UUID varId, 
                                         HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
   HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpMethod.valueOf(httpServletRequest.getMethod());
   if (httpMethod == httpMethod.GET) {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Please, be aware of [@GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html), [@PostMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html) and [@RequestMapping(method="...")](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--) - you can specify which HTTP methods are allowed for a given endpoint.

Comment: Okay awesome thanks. The only reason I'm not specifying the method type is because this endpoint is going to be used for relaying information to another endpoint. So my intention was to pull out the method type and the wildcard of the URI and then relay that over to the destination endpoint. (This is a part of a proxy). Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It's probably better to have some proxy behind your application, something like [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) or [apache httpd's mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) or [agiee](https://docs.apigee.com/). So you can configure all redirect stuff there instead of in your code

Comment: sorry, I meant in front of your application, not behind.

Comment: My scenario is a little odd. I have an application (A) sending a request to another service(B), but A sends access tokens for authentication and B only accepts basic authentication. So, my requirement is to build a "proxy" between the two that takes the access token, authenticates the user, and then relays the request to B after converting the credentials to basic auth. With that info, is my method an alright way of doing that? This is only going to be used for testing.

Comment: I would search for some way of doing that using an existing proxy solution. But if it's for testing purposes and serves as a temporary solution - probably you could leave it as is.